# CoreBluetooth willRestoreState not called in iOS 7.1

Tags: objective-c, ios7, background, restore, kill

Will restore state delegate method is not called when system kills the app in background
i am using the below code in button action to check system kill

```
kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
```

When i kill the app using this function but willrestore state delegate method  is not called in my application i am using the below code to connect to the central manager.

```
 dispatch_queue_t centralQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mycentral", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);// or however you want to create your dispatch_queue_t
NSDictionary *options = @{
                          CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:@"restoremyapp",
                          CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                          };

self.CM = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:centralQueue options:options];
```

i have searched stack overflow and in some link they said if we use dispatch queue it will works but for me its not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoreBluetooth state preservation issue: willRestoreState not called in iOS 7.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412376/corebluetooth-state-preservation-issue-willrestorestate-not-called-in-ios-7-1)

Comment: Thanks i got a solution ,you need to use shouldrestorestate application method in appdelagate and always return yes to the function then it work.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you say more information about your shouldrestorate application method?

Comment: To call "willrestorestate" method in corebluetooth .we need to use shouldRestoreApplicationState method in app delegate and we need to return always yes to that method.                                                                         E.g : -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder {
return YES;
}

Answer (score 0):

This might best be marked as a duplicate of other questions on the matter.

In short, it appears as though you're out of luck (we found the same thing) — evidence suggests that this functionality will help you restore connections to bluetooth devices or will ensure that *interrupted* sightings of peripherals are still sent to you, but will *not* allow scanning to continue in the background after your app is killed.

It [looks as though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20531140/134686) this is just not supported.