# iOS Bluetooth monitoring without iBeacon monitoring

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I am trying to create an app that wakes up to background mode whenever it detects a new peripheral that advertises a pre-defined service. I want the wakeup to happen even if the user minimized the app, the app was suspended, the app was killed by the user or the app was killed by the system. Obviously I also want the app to be accepted to the app store (so don't suggest solutions like adding all possible *UIBackgroundModes* and run in the background forever...).

I can add *bluetooth-central* to the *UIBackgroundModes* because my app fits the description [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23) - it needs to communicate with a peripheral in the background.

I found some documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW5) about *State Preservation and Restoration*. It describes a scenario where an app connects to a bluetooth door lock, and the connection breaks because the user went far away from the door. From what I understand, when the user returns to the door and the iPhone detects the door lock (by its MAC address, I suppose), it reconnects to the door lock and wakes up the app in Background mode (please correct me if I am wrong).

I don't want to preserve a connection to the peripheral (and waste its battery). I want the app to run *scanForPeripheralWithServices* that will wake up the app when a new peripheral is detected, even if the app was killed\suspended by the user\system.

I found a relevant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22244674/242417) to a different question, saying I could simulate an app-termination-by-the-OS using `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);` and then, if my app uses *State Preservation & Restoration*, it should wake up (right?).

When my app detects a new\old peripheral, I want it to create a quick connection, read some characteristics and disconnect. Unforetunately this is not possible with iBeacon Monitoring that does not give a Peripheral object (only a region). I know I can detect the peripheral by running *scanForPeripheralsWithServices* after my app enters the iBeacon region, but this feels strange - a direct continuous *scanForPeripheralsWithServices* that survives suspension & kill, would make much more sense.

Any ideas?

If you know for sure that this is not possible, and depending on iBeacon Monitoring is the only way, please let me know.

Comment: If the user kills your app then there is nothing you can do.  Your app won't run until the user relaunches your app.  The other part is straightforward. You can scan for a peripheral offering a particular service in the background and you can also have a pending connect for known peripherals which will automatically complete when that peripheral is seen.

Comment: Here is some sample code that demonstrate background scanning and connection https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground

Comment: So you're saying that even if a connection is made, if the user killed the app from the app switcher it will not be relaunched? Not even after a reconnection? (will there be any reconnection?).

Comment: What happens if I call `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL)` on `willResignActive` right before the user even has a chance to kill it from the app switcher? Will it mean that the app never gets killed by the user, and therefore will wake up?

Comment: In general in iOS if the user kills the app from the app switcher then it is assumed that the user wanted it dead and iOS will not relaunch the app until the user taps the icon

Comment: I am not sure what happens if you kill the app yourself, but Apple will probably reject your app for crashing.  I suspect that if the user swipes up, even if your app isn't running then that will be taken as a sign to not relaunch that app

Comment: So what's the deal with the door lock? If the user killed the app (which iPhone users tend to do oftenly) and the user returns to the door lock, a reconnection won't be made? Does the user have to relaunch the app in order to open the door lock? How do handsfree devices (such handsfree speakers in cars) work? How do they launch apps on iPhones? (do they?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98807/discussion-between-oren-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part of the question is:

> I want the app to run scanForPeripheralWithServices that will wake up the app when a new peripheral is detected, even if the app was killed\suspended by the user\system.

Unfortunately, this is not possible with `CoreBluetooth` alone.  If the user kills an app, it will not get new OS launch events from `CoreBluetooth` unless the user manually launches the app again.

Fortunately, `CoreLocation` does not have this restriction.  Since iOS 7.1, it will launch a killed app to notify it of a Bluetooth beacon detection.  This would allow you a few seconds of background running time to scan for peripherals.

Comment: Great. If only your answer was at the beginning of: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW5 ...